# Editor Calendar in Primefaces 3.5 cell value is lost?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

is that I have a grid that dynamically genre, I mean I add empty rows to the grid, first thought to use primefaces in Cell Editor, so that the value is stored in the list of beans 
List, works but the problem that I have is on the calendar, when I select one and is stored, it is stored in the list, I checked it does not execute the ajax event, you lose the value of the date.

```
<p:commandButton value="Añadir dia" update="dataTable" actionListener="#{regDPNL.registrarNuevoDia}" />

<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="dpnl" value="#{regDPNL.listdpnl}" paginatorPosition="top"
 rows="20" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" editable="true" editMode="cell"  

   <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{regDPNL.onCellEdit}" />                

   <p:column width="25%">  
      <f:facet name="header">  
         <h:outputText value="NOMBRE" />  
      </f:facet>
      <p:cellEditor>  
         <f:facet name="output"><p:inputText value="#{dpnl.nombre}" /></f:facet>  
         <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{dpnl.nombre}" /></f:facet>  
      </p:cellEditor>  
   </p:column>

   <p:column width="20%">  
      <f:facet name="header">  
         <h:outputText value="DESDE" />  
      </f:facet>
      <p:cellEditor> 
         <f:facet name="output"><p:inputText value="#{dpnl.fechaDesde}" /></f:facet>  
         <f:facet name="input"><p:calendar value="#{dpnl.fechaDesde}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" /></f:facet>  
      </p:cellEditor>  
   </p:column>

   <p:column width="20%">  
      <f:facet name="header">  
         <h:outputText value="HASTA" />  
      </f:facet>
      <p:cellEditor>  
         <f:facet name="output"><p:inputText value="#{dpnl.fechaHasta}" /></f:facet>  
         <f:facet name="input"><p:calendar value="#{dpnl.fechaHasta}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" /></f:facet>  
      </p:cellEditor> 
   </p:column>

   <p:column width="5%">  
      <f:facet name="header">  
         <h:outputText value="ELIMINAR" />  
      </f:facet>  
      <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-editar" title="Delete Periodo" style="background:#fff">  
      </p:commandButton>
   </p:column> 
</p:dataTable>
```

Java code:

```
private List<DetallePeriodoBean> listdpnl = new PeriodoNoLaborable();
private DetallePeriodoBean detallePeriodoNoLaborable = new ArrayList<DetallePeriodoBean>();

public void registrarNuevoDia() {                
   detallePeriodoNoLaborable = new DetallePeriodoBean();
   this.listdpnl.add(detallePeriodoNoLaborable);
}

public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {  
   Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();  
   Object newValue = event.getNewValue();    
   if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {  
      System.out.println("==> Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
   } 
}
```

http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_8690487captura.png

Comment: Your meaningful code for the question is based in the column of the date. Please, remove other columns as they're irrelevant for the question. Appart from that, is your `dataTable` wrapped into an `h:form`?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem.

The solution is very simple (after a lot of testing and error)
You must add id attribute to your  tag,
for instance:

```
<p:calendar id="date_selector" value="#{dpnl.fechaHasta}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

Answer (score 0):

At the facet named output use the tag h:outputText instead of p:inputText

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use java.util.date for your date fields(i.e fechaDesde etc) in your bean.